# (C++) Constructor, default parameters, "call of overloaded... ambigous"

Tags: c++, inline, default-constructor, ambiguous

i'm new to this site, after doing some research I could not find a problem similar to mine(some questions looked like mine but their code was different)

So basically what i'm trying to do is to representing the framebuffer matrix with all different colors values. I'm coding a class named "Point", and I have one constructor, using default arguments, here it is :

**Point.h**

```cpp
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
#include <iostream>



class Point
{
    protected:
        int x;
        int y;

    public:
        Point(int=0,int=0);
        Point(const &Point);
        void showC() const;
        static void showC(Point);
        virtual ~Point();


};

#endif // POINT_H
```

**Point.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Point.h"

using namespace std;

Point::Point(int a,int b)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;
}

Point::~Point()
{}

void Point::showC() const
{ cout << x << " " << y << endl; }


void Point::showC(Point P)
{ cout << P.x << " " << P.y << endl; }
```

But the problem is when I try to compile the program

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"



using namespace std;

int main()
{
 Point P1;
 Point P2(2);
 Point P3(4,-7);
 cout << "Call of function member showC\n";
 P1.showC();
 P2.showC();
 P3.showC();
cout << "Call of static function showC\n";
Point::showC(P1);
Point::showC(P2);
Point::showC(P3);

    return 0;
}
```

There is an error when I create Point P2 :

- **"Call of overloaded 'Point(int)' is ambigous"**

On all the others question i read, either it was not the same problem or they had a default constructor in addition to a constructor with default argument which cause ambiguity of which constructor to use if you create an object without argument.

On a book i'm reading to improve skills on c++, there is this sample that is working somehow, and that's why I don't really understand

Here is the sample :

**main.cpp**

```cpp
class point
{
private :
int x;
int y;

Point (int abs=0, int ord=0) //inline constructor
 {x=abs; y=ord;}

bool coincide(point);

};

    bool point::coincide(point pt)
{ return ( (pt.x==x) && (pt.y==y) );
} 

int main()
{
point a, b(1), c(1,0);
cout << "a and b : " << a.coincide(b) << " ou " b.coincide(a) << "\n"
cout << "b et c : " << b.coincide(c) << " ou " << c.coincide(b) << "\n"
}
```

However he grouped everything in the main.cpp files, and his constructor is inline.

Can anyone explain to me why is the sample working, and why my program is not ? I guess there is a mechanism that i don't understand...

Thanks in advance

RE-EDIT : I copied all the code

Comment: Please read the guidelines for posting code,  you really need to post the *exact* and complete code that gives the problem

Comment: Unable to reproduce, you are NOT showing your exact code: http://ideone.com/cReVEs. In addition yours neither compile since `Class Point:` is not valid C++.

Comment: I'm editing it right now and give the full code

Comment: From the error message it looks like you also have a `Point(int)` constructor.

Comment: Still there are problem     Point(const &Point); what is the type?

Comment: Well I don't have any, by the way I finished to edit my post, and gave the full code of my program as well as in the sample

Comment: Point(const &Point);  means nothing you will have to specify the type

Comment: Hariom Singh, again, badly copied by me, I inverted the place of the '&' operator indeed, thanks for telling me, i'll correct this !

Comment: No problem friend , don't be in hurry just post your code properly

Comment: Yes my bad, I didn't even notice it somehow, and by the way, I corrected it, and now it works O_O I have an other error but I can correct it myself, the overloaded error is no longer a problem. How can I make this problem as "solved" ? And how can I highlight your anwser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are  mixing both python and c++ way of creating class

python do use `:` **class Point:**

for declaring in class , c++ uses `{}` like **class Point {};**
Below works by changing the class declaration.

Just added a cout in your constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;


public:
    Point(int=0,int=0);
};

Point::Point(int a, int b)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
    cout<<x<<y<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Point P1;
    Point P2(2);
    Point P3(4,-7);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
00
20
4-7
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**After question edit**
Removed your buggy line and it works perfectly

```
Point(const &Point);

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
protected:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Point(int=0,int=0);
    //Point(const &Point);
    void showC() const;
    static void showC(Point);
    virtual ~Point();


};
Point::Point(int a,int b)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;
}

Point::~Point()
{}

void Point::showC() const
{ cout << x << " " << y << endl; }


void Point::showC(Point P)
{ cout << P.x << " " << P.y << endl; }

int main()
{
    Point P1;
    Point P2(2);
    Point P3(4,-7);
    cout << "Call of function member showC\n";
    P1.showC();
    P2.showC();
    P3.showC();
    cout << "Call of static function showC\n";
    Point::showC(P1);
    Point::showC(P2);
    Point::showC(P3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Call of function member showC
0 0
2 0
4 -7
Call of static function showC
0 0
2 0
4 -7
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

After edit I guess you want to use copy constructor just change it to

```
  Point(const Point &p2) {x = p2.x; y = p2.y; }
```

Comment: It was actually me not copying properly, in my code there isn't ":" after the Class point. I edited and gave the full code. But it looks like the problem happens when I compile seperated files

Comment: Indeed, i'll highlight your anwser,  I inverted the place of '&' operator on my copy constructor ! Problem solved ! Thanks for help, all of you are really fast :') ! I'll take care next time before posting, I thought everything was right but I did a lot of mistake

Comment: I think you want to use copy constructor     Point(const Point &p2) {x = p2.x; y = p2.y; }

Comment: Yes exactly, but I somehow wrote Point(const &Point) instead of Point(const Point&). What a terrible mistake... it's one of the most basic thing and I still did it bad..